# Why isn’t this a tautology: $((p → q) ∧ (r → ¬q)) → (p ∧ r)$?

Tags: logic

I can't figure out why $((p → q) ∧ (r → ¬q)) → (p ∧ r)$ isn’t a tautology.

I tried solving it like this:

$$((p ∧ ¬p) ∨ (r ∧ q)) ∨ (p ∧ r)$$
resulting in $(T) ∨ (p ∧ r)$ in the end that should result in $T$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: What happens if both $p$ and $r$ are true?

Comment: The antecedent is true when $q$ is true and $r$ is false. But this makes the consequent false, and thus the whole sentence is false in those circumstances. This means it's not a tautology

Comment: What you're doing wrong : $(p ∧ ¬p)$ is a contradiction (negation of excluded middle) therefore the left part of $((p ∧ ¬p) \lor (r ∧ q))$ is equivalent to "False". So the whole should result in $(r \land q) \lor (p \land r)$

Comment: Check with Truth table: 3 prop letters means $2^3=8$ rows: not so difficult.

Comment: As @BorisEng says, $p\vee\neg p$ is true, however, $p\wedge\neg p$ is false!  Don't confuse them.

Comment: However, the "opposite" of your sentence is a tautology: $((p\to q) \land (r\to \neg q)) \to \neg (p\land r)$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 2):

$$((p \Rightarrow q) \land (r \Rightarrow ¬q)) \Rightarrow (p ∧ r)$$

If it is January, then I am cold.

If it is July, then I am not cold.

Therefore, it is January and July.

Would you accept that?

Answer (score 0):

Using $a\to b=\lnot a\lor b$,

$$\lnot((\lnot p\lor q)\land(\lnot r\lor \lnot q))\lor(p\land r)$$
$$((p\land \lnot q)\lor(r\land q))\lor(p\land r)$$
$$(p\land(\lnot q\lor r))\lor(r\land q)$$

is falsified with all false.

---

Using bitwise operations and the hexadecimal representation,

$$p=00001111_b=0F_h, q=00110011_b=33_h, r=01010101_b=55h$$

$$p\to q=F3$$
$$r\to\lnot q=EE$$
$$(p\to q)\land(r\to\lnot q)=E2$$
$$p\land r=05$$
$$(p\to q)\land(r\to\lnot q)\to(p\land r)=1D\ne FF.$$

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you swapped a $p$ for $q$.

You have:

$$((p ∧ ¬p) ∨ (r ∧ q)) ∨ (p ∧ r)$$

When it should be

$$((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (r ∧ q)) ∨ (p ∧ r)$$

It also looks like you made the mistake of thinking that $p ∧ ¬p$ is true. That would be the case in classical logic if it were OR rather than AND: $p ∨ ¬p$.

The expression simplifies by the [consensus rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem) to the following:

$$(p \land \neg q) \vee (q \land r)$$

Answer (score 0):

We want to see this is not a tautology. This is the case if we find a choice of $p$, $q$ and $r$ so that

1. $(p → q) ∧ (r → ¬q)$ is false
2. $p ∧ r$ is true

In order for $(p → q) ∧ (r → ¬q)$ to be true, both $p → q$ and $r → ¬q$ must be true. Let's choose $q$ true. Then, as $¬q$ is false, $r$ must be false.

OK, we're done: choose $p$ true, $q$ true and $r$ *true*. Then

1. $p → q$ is true and $r → ¬q$ is false, so $(p → q) ∧ (r → ¬q)$ is false
2. $p ∧ r$ is true

Therefore $((p → q) ∧ (r → ¬q)) → (p ∧ r)$ is false.